# How to get ManagedObjectContext from a Segue View

Tags: macos, core-data, nsviewcontroller

In my MacOS App, I have 2 views: a Main view "Main" and a "show" segue to anther view called "Variant". Both views have a TableView and an arrayController which should display data from the data model.
How do I get ManagedObjectContext for my arrayController in the  View "Variant" ?

[image]

There is no issue with the main view to get it:

```
self.view.window.windowController.document.managedObjectContext
```

In View "Variant" however, I have no window assigned. I also see no way to access view "Main" to get it from there.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it made. View Variant has its own ViewController attached, and at ViewDidLoad I can get the context through the main window controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        objectContext = (NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.windowController?.document?.managedObjectContext)!
}
```

I also had to set "prepares context" for the arrayController to get the data displayed in the tableview